# Trace TCP packets instead of TCP connections

Tags: ebpf, bcc-bpf

As the title says, is it possible to trace TCP packets, instead of TCP connections using bcc/ebpf?
If so, how would i do it?
I've checked all BCC tools, and if possible I'd like to stray from using XDP.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid XDP? Why do you want to trace packets instead of connections? Understanding the motives will help propose solutions. There are many different ways to do what you're asking.

Comment: @pchaigno I'd like to avoid XDP for now, since I'd like to create another version further down the line using XDP. As for tracing packets instead of connections, it's what it was requested of me.

Comment: Did you check tc-bpf?

Comment: @pchaigno I've checked it due to your suggestion, and while i found the documentation limited, I've found this https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/8422cd449ad2e60414a4508aa4a150a9db39c4a3/examples/networking/tcp_mon_block/src/tcp_mon_block.c#L95. If i understand correctly, the function handle_egress is what i want. Thanks for the help!